# The iOS9 NetworkExtension Packet Tunnel Provider Target should be how to use?

Tags: ios, ios9, vpn, nevpnmanager, networkextension

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXgE2.png)

[Open func](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSfDk.png)

Code in the picturePacket Tunnel Provider.m is so written, the ProvisioningProfiles are set up. It has already applied to the NetworkExtension.entitlements.

I would like to run the main program, then execution target, but the target time is running out wrong.

Will I doing wrong? PacketTunnelProvider this Target should be how to use ?

(Code in the picture)

Comment: Instead of adding code as image, try writing it in your question only. It will be better for both you and others

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. To run the PacketTunnelProvider, you need to use the function startVPNTunnel()

And since it's can throw an exception, you need to do something like

```
    do {
        try vpnManager!.connection.startVPNTunnel()
        }
   catch {
         }
```

Comment: hello, I was in the main program, wrote [self.manager.connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError: & startError]; I added a new picture, you can look at.

Comment: My error was running Target when direct crash, open VPN instead of running after time.